# cmd.exe is hanging unexpectedly depending on where the file I use is located

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, process

This has got to be one of the strangest things I have ever observed. Consider the following Java program:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class StrangeError {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd",
                "/c",
                "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\" amd64 && set"
            ).start();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it with `javac StrangeError.java`, copied it to my server running Windows Server 2012 R2, and ran it with `java StrangeError`.

Here's where things start to get weird. The program hangs, waiting for the process it spawned to finish. This is not the expected behavior, since the `vcvarsall.bat` script should complete immediately as well as `set`.

So I started playing around and discovered the following:

- Removing `set` causes `vcvarsall.bat` to terminate
- Removing `vcvarsall.bat` causes `set` to terminate
- Replacing `&&` with `||` causes everything to terminate correctly
- Copying `vcvarsall.bat` to a location on the desktop and changing the path causes everything to terminate correctly
- A [nearly equivalent program](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24362333/) works fine in Go using the same commands
- I get [this output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24362506/) if I run everything in WinDbg and interrupt the process after it hangs
- This does not appear to be reproducible with `vcvarsall.bat` from MSVC2013 but is also reproducible with MSVC2015 on Windows 10

What on earth is wrong with the original program? If I copy and paste the entire command (`cmd /c "C:\...`) into Start->Run, it immediately launches  `cmd` and terminates, as expected.

Is this a bug with Java? Is this a bug with Windows?

Comment: Have you tried to replace `&&` by `&`?

Comment: @aschipfl I tried a single '&' and it still hangs. Also, the double '&&' has a useful property - it only runs the second command if the first succeeds.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a system with no anti-virus software installed?

Comment: @HarryJohnston none of the machines I was able to reproduce this on have any third-party antivirus software installed. The Win10 machine has Windows Defender installed but the Win2012 machine has nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Is this a bug with Java? Is this a bug with Windows?*

It's a bug in your code. :-)

By default, a child process created using a ProcessBuilder object has output redirected to a pipe, the parent end of which can be obtained using `Process.getInputStream()` and which is not automatically drained if your code does not make use of it.

Since your code simply calls `.waitFor` without making any provision to drain the pipe, it will deadlock as soon as the pipe's buffer overflows.  I believe the default buffer size is 4,096 bytes.  On my machine, the output of the command you're running is 5,192 bytes, but this will vary depending on the original contents of the environment block.  (From the sounds of it, the output length in your environment is borderline, only just above the limit, so that even small changes like changing the version of VS make a difference.)

One of the many possible solutions, depending on what you're actually trying to do, is to tell Java not to pipe the child's output:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class StrangeError {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd",
                "/c",
                "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\" amd64 && set"
            );
            processb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
            Process process = processb.start();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am crying tears of joy over this. You have no idea how many hours have been wasted pouring through source code, stepping through stack traces, firing up debuggers, and testing on different environments. **Thank you so very much!**

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to read standard input and output error inside the same ProcessBuilder.

So you need to create two ProcessBuilder

```
Process process1 = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd",
            "/c",
            "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\",
            "amd64");

Process process2 = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd",
        "/c",
        "set"); 

process1.start();
if (process1.waitFor() == 0) {
    process2.start();
    if (process2.waitFor() == 0) {
        // Successfull execution
    }
}
```

And one thing : I don't think it is a good practice to do shell/batch launches with Java (or another language). Maybe you should use a script (shell, batch, python, perl...) to control standard input/output streams.

Comment: But the documentation for `waitFor()` that you linked to states that the return value is `the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination`

Comment: Also, I cannot launch two `ProcessBuilder`s or the environment variables set in the first will not appear when I invoke `set` in the second.

Comment: Good point about waitFor, sorry for the mistake. But I don't know why variables will not appear in the second process (because you are in the same session). Did you try it ?

Comment: The child process that Java launches has a separate environment than its parent. Any additional variables that are added will only be visible to the child and will disappear when it terminates. The second child process will never see them.

Comment: Right, maybe you could read this interesting post : http://stackoverflow.com/q/37653982/7529228

Comment: That answer is not correct, at least on Windows. The fact that my Java code works with `vcvarsall.bat` from VS2013 demonstrates this.

Comment: Strange... did you try to make a diff between the 2013 and 2015 version ?

Comment: Here's the diff: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24363283/ I don't see anything unusual upon initial inspection.